# Why SootMethod is not serializable?

Tags: java, serialization, soot

I am doing programming analysis for Java​ programs with soot. I customize a class which includes a field whose type is SootMethod. I want to save a large number of these objects and use them in another program. So, I find serialization meet my requirement. However, it triggers out the NotSerializableException because of the SootMethod.

What should I do if I want to save the objects with this SootMethod field? Why SootMethod is not serializable?

Comment: I'd post your question on the Soot mailing list: http://www.sable.mcgill.ca/mailman/listinfo/soot-list/

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because `SootMethod` dose not implement `java.io.Serializable` so it is impossible to serialize instance of this Class , so if you want to serialize the object that contains a `SootMethod` type field you have 2 ways :

1. Make this field `transient` ! so it is possible to serialize the object , but when you deserialize the object this filed will be null.
2. Make `SootMethod` Class serializable by implement `java.io.Serializable` for this Class.

Generally a Class could be serializale if implements `java.io.Serializable` interface and all fields implements this interface too and if a field not implements it so this filed must be transient.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I just curious why this method isn't designed to be serializable. In soot, there are many other classes which are serializable (e.g. Unit, Body, etc.) However, SootMethod is not. In this (https://www.sable.mcgill.ca/soot/doc/soot/class-use/SootMethod.html) webpage which introduces the use of SootMethod, it said: "Serialization has to be avoided by static analyses since each object comes out of the same place." It seems that this class is intended to set as non-serializable. Why?